# Javascript How To Format An Integer As A Currency String?

Tags: javascript, currency

I have an integer stored as US cents, ie 1700 cents. How can I convert that to a string that is $17.00 using javascript? I have tried `toFixed` and `Intl.NumberFormat` but they return $1700?

Comment: Have you tried dividing the value by 100 first...?

Comment: Can you show the way in which you used `toFixed()` and `Intl.numberFormat`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleString()` function for this.

```js
var cents = 1629;
var dollars = cents / 100;
dollars = dollars.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
console.log(dollars);
```